# OSX bash script does not run from cron

Tags: macos, shell, cron

I have a bash script, that runs just fine from the command line. After adding it to the root users crontab (sudo crontab -e), I find it does not run. Here is the cron task:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /Users/lorenzot/Documents/scripts/restart-net.sh
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Net script" | logger -s  >> /Library/Logs/netlog.log

# Ping twice just to be sure
/sbin/ping -c 2 8.8.8.8
/sbin/ping -c 2 8.8.8.8
if [ $? -ge 1 ]; then
echo "Network down :("

ifconfig en1 down
ifconfig en1 up
             exit 1
else
    echo "Network up! :)"
exit 0
fi
```

The script is owned by root and of course, it is executable (766) and it does exist at the correct path.

I'm not seeing an entry in the log file, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of writing to a log file. I've tried a few different variations including:

```
syslog -s -k Facility com.apple.console \
                Level Error \
                            Sender restartscript \
Message "Restart network script run"
```

But nothing is written to any log. Nevertheless, I would expect to see a log entry for the cron task having executed.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: check the mail account for `root` and see if any output/error messages from these jobs are appearing there (you should see some, or something else is wrong (or you're not telling us the whole story ;-) ) ). . Hopefully the error message will tell you what the problem is. Good luck.

Comment: Change your command line to `/Users/lorenzot/Documents/scripts/restart-net.sh || touch /tmp/cron_run.tmp` or similar to make sure cron indeed kicked off the task (or tried to).

Comment: Honest, that's the whole story. I'm not sure what else I could tell you. The script and cron task were posted.

Comment: I added the touch, but not file in /tmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'logger -s` sends a copy of the message to stderr, not stdout. Also, you can pass the message as an argument, rather than via stdin. Try this:

```
logger -s "Net script" 2>> /Library/Logs/netlog.log
```

Comment: This did it! It seems it actually was running, but the output was going to the wrong place. But upon further research, it seems Apple is deprecating cron in favor of launchd. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html I'll investigate migrating to launchd.

Comment: @user675712 launchd is generally preferred over cron, but cron is still supported and I'd expect it to be around for a long time. I wouldn't worry about migrating until/unless you see a clear advantage to launchd.